# Upgrade free app to paid with in app purchase?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, in-app-purchase

So I have a paid App already for sale on the app store. I'm using the same project and creating a new target for a free/lite version. For the users that install the free version, I will have a buy button to allow them to buy the app. I would assume when they hit the buy button, I would prompt for their password and then the new app ID would be recognized allowing for the paid version? Is this how to implement a free and paid version? So far I just have the buy button in the free target, and the paid target. Am I doing this right so far? How do I proceed from here? Like programming my button for in app purchase for full version? This is certainly not a clear issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the past I made one target thats free to download. In the app you have a button that starts the in app purchase process (you don't do anything with name and password apple takes care of tht when you make the appropriate calls). Once the user successfully purchases the app, I set a boolean value in `NSUserDefaults` like 'isPurchased'.

In your code, anywhere where you would allow the user to either use the pro upgrade or free trial just check the value of the bool 'isPurchased' and either display the extra content or not.

**Edit
Try following this tutorial. It shows you how to set up in app purchases and how to start the process using a button.
[In App Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases)

Comment: Yes, i know apple handles the authentication for in app purchases. But, how do we start that process with a button? And set a boolean in NSUserDefaults and call it?

Comment: I added a link above... Try giving that a look